# Image rotation getting in the way of things

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I've got a wheel consisting of 3 images.

[image]

When I rotate the wheel, the image gets in the way of the submit button:

[image]

Let's say that resizing the image wasn't an option, how can I make it so that all the other elements are "on top" of the images, so that when it rotates, everything still works?

All 3 wheels are within #circles:

```
#circles{
    background-color:#FFF;
    min-height:500px;
}
```

and each has their own ID.

```
#ring-outer{
    position:absolute;
}

#ring-middle{
    position:absolute;
}

#ring-inner{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: A picture may be worth 1000 words, but here code is worth 1000 pictures. Post some please.

Comment: Have you tried setting z-index of the submit button to being on top of the images? For example: z-index of images is 1 and z-index of button is 100.

Comment: No I have not. I'll try that, thanks "n00b".
Edit: It works! I never really knew what z-index did until now. Thanks again. Feel free to answer the question and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need modify the z-index and/or change the source order of your markup so that the form controls are *below* #circles in the markup. If you went that route, you'd need to use absolute positioning to show the form controls where you want them.

Posting code will help me provide a better answer.